# Informix SQL update command error 746

Tags: sql, sql-update, informix

I tried to update the field "contract_id" in the table "contract_scan_image".
However, the update was failed and an error "746: Field contract_id and type of contract_scan_image cannot be updated!" was shown.

My SQL command is:

```
update contract_scan_image
   set contract_id = '14864730'
 where contract_id = '1486473'
   and type = 'RM'
   and account = '00193400944'
```

Does anyone know what happened and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Error message -746 is for user-defined errors.  It typically is used in stored procedures in a RAISE EXCEPTION statement:

```
RAISE EXCEPTION -746, 0, "Field contract_id and type of contract_scan_image cannot be updated!"
```

The actual message text for error -746 in the message files is:

```
%s
```

That is, it prints the string it is given as a string.

So, you are going to need to track down the triggers and stored procedures invoked by those triggers on the `contract_scan_image` table, and deduce from where the error is generated what you are doing wrong.  Superficially, though, it appears that you are not allowed to alter the contract ID, yet that is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, I would take a look at a list of Reserved words in SQL - https://drupal.org/node/141051

I would get in the habit of surrounding fields with `` See below:

```
update contract_scan_image
set `contract_id` = '14864730'
where `contract_id` = '1486473'
and `type` = 'RM'
and `account` = '00193400944'
```

** Note - type is a reserved word

Comment: Err...what makes you think back-quotes might be a good idea in Informix?  MySQL uses them, but MySQL is weird (as in, it is the only major SQL DBMS to use that notation for delimited identifiers).  The question is about Informix, and Informix will treat the back-quotes as syntax errors.  Also, Informix is pretty lax and allows you to use most keywords as identifiers in most places without special treatment.  In this context, TYPE is not part of the problem.

Comment: hmmm i guess you could be right. wasn't really sure if you were querying right out of a sql db using sql pro or something like that. Informix is a different story, your right

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by something being triggered. Then no table can be modified by UPDATE command.

Finally I deleted the record I want to update.  Then added back the modified record.

I copy the error description here from [the net](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes/src/tpc/n746.htm) for reference.

BTW, I asked my supervisor and he said he did trigger something to cause this. (He didn't tell me how to un-trigger it...)

---

-746
THE SQL STATEMENT IN FUNCTION, TRIGGER, OR IN STORED PROCEDURE name VIOLATES THE NESTING SQL RESTRICTION

Explanation
If a table is being modified (by INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, or MERGE), the table can not be accessed by the lower level nesting SQL statement.

If any table is being accessed by a SELECT statement, no table can be modified (by INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, or MERGE) in any lower level nesting SQL statement.

System action
The SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE or MERGE SQL statement failed.

Programmer response
Remove the failing statement from the named function, trigger or the stored procedure.

SQLSTATE

### 57053